# How does this yield work in this generator?

Tags: python, generator, yield

```
def read_large_file(file_handler, block_size=10000):
    block = []
    for line in file_handler:
        block.append(line)
        if len(block) == block_size:
            yield block
            block = []

    # don't forget to yield the last block
    if block:
        yield block

with open(path) as file_handler:
    for block in read_large_file(file_handler):
        print(block)
```

I am reading this piece of code above written by another. For this line:

```
if len(block) == block_size:
   yield block
   block = []
```

Does the `block=[]` have a chance to be executed? I had thought `yield` is like a `return` statement. Also, why is there an `if block` checking?

Comment: Yes. You can say `yield` is a way to pause execution and resume it again from the next line. Place a print statement to check if it gets executed.

Comment: By adding yield to your function, the function becomes a generator function. For details you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)

Comment: BTW, the function will only yield if the size is exactly `block_size`. It might be better to use `if len(block) >= block_size:`.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it will be executed when the function resumes on the next iteration. Remember, yield is like a pause button for a generator, and generators are usually used within a loop. The yield is *sort of* returning a value (i say "sort of", because `yield` is not the same as `return`), but when the generator is next accessed, it will pick up at that same spot. The purpose of `block = []` is to reset the block to an empty list before the next go around (it might be faster to use `block.clear()` instead).

This code is building up blocks from a file, and handing them back to the caller as soon as they are sufficiently large. The last `if` block is to return the last bit, if there is some leftover that didn't fit in a complete block.

Answer (score 1):

`yield` produces the next output of the generator and then allows it to continue generating values.

Here, lines are read in to a block (a list of lines). Whenever a block is populated with enough lines it's yielded as the next value from the generator, and then the block is re-initialized to an empty list, and the reading can continue.